# Conditional permalink structure

Tags: permalinks

I want a function to apply multiple permalink structure for posts under certain conditions.

For example, if post date is before 2014, I want the permalink structure to be:

```
/%category%/%post_id%/
```

And when the post date is after 2014, I want the permalink structure to be:

```
/%post_id%/
```